# 2D numpy array search (equivalent toMatlab's intersect 'rows' option)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 4 column numpy arrays (2D) with several hundred (float) rows (cap and usp) in each. Considering a subset of 3 columns in each array (e.g. `capind=cap[:,:3]`):

1. There are many common rows between both arrays.
2. Each row tuple/"triplet" is unique in each array.

I am looking for an an efficient means to identify these common three value (row) subsets across both arrays while somehow retaining the 4th column from both arrays for further processing. In essence I'm looking for a great numpy way to do the equivalent of Matlab's intersect function with row option(i.e. `([c, ia, ib]=intersect(capind, uspind, 'rows');)`.

Which returns the index of the matching rows, so that it's now trivial to get the matching triplets and value from the 4th column from the original array (`matchcap=cap[ia,:]`).

---

My current approach is based upon a similar question on the forum as I cannot find a good match for my problem. However, this approach seems a little inefficient considering my goal (I also haven't fully solved my problem):

The arrays are something like this:

```
cap=array([[  2.50000000e+01,   1.27000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      9.81997200e-06],
   [  2.60000000e+01,   1.27000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      9.14296800e+00],
   [  2.70000000e+01,   1.27000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      2.30137100e-04],
   ...,
   [  6.10000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      8.44939900e-03],
   [  6.20000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      4.77729100e-03],
   [  6.30000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      1.40343500e-03]])

usp=array([[  4.10000000e+01,   1.31000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      5.24197200e-06],
   [  4.20000000e+01,   1.31000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      8.39178800e-04],
   [  4.30000000e+01,   1.31000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
      1.20279900e+01],
   ...,
   [  4.70000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      2.48667700e-02],
   [  4.80000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      4.23304600e-03],
   [  4.90000000e+01,   1.80000000e+02,   1.06000000e+02,
      1.02051300e-03]])
```

I then convert each 4 column array (usp and cap) into a three column array (capind and uspind shown below as integers for ease of viewing).

```
capind=array([[ 25, 127,   1],
   [ 26, 127,   1],
   [ 27, 127,   1],
   ...,
   [ 61, 180, 106],
   [ 62, 180, 106],
   [ 63, 180, 106]])
uspind=array([[ 41, 131,   1],
   [ 42, 131,   1],
   [ 43, 131,   1],
   ...,
   [ 47, 180, 106],
   [ 48, 180, 106],
   [ 49, 180, 106]])
```

Using a set operation gives me the matching triplets: `carray=np.array([x for x in set(tuple(x) for x in capind) & set(tuple(x) for x in uspind)])`.

This seems to work fairly well for finding the common row values from both uspind and capind arrays. I now need to get the 4th columns value from the matching rows (i.e. compare carray with the first three columns of the original source array (cap and usp) and somehow grab the value from the 4th column).

Is there a better a more efficient way to achieve this? Otherwise, any help on the best means to retrieve the 4th column values from the source arrays would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dictionaries.

```
capind = {tuple(row[:3]):row[3] for row in cap}
uspind = {tuple(row[:3]):row[3] for row in usp}

keys = capind.viewkeys() & uspind.viewkeys()
for key in keys:
    # capind[key] and uspind[key] are the fourth columns
```

Comment: This is almost there with one small correction.`capind = {tuple(row[:3]):row[3] for row in cap}
uspind = {tuple(row[:3]):row[3] for row in usp}`

Comment: I'd like to retain the array structure as I don't really want to iterate through a dictionary. I need to do some array math later on the common elements in cap and usp.

Comment: There is a another good reason to stick with array datatype however; performance of this method will be far from ideal.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn: What do you mean? If you have another method that you think will be faster, you should profile it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the assumptions you have that the rows are unique in each matrix and that there are common rows, here is one solution.  The basic idea is to concatenate the two arrays, sort it so the similar rows are together and then do a difference across the rows.  The first three values should be close to zero if the rows are the same.

[Original]

```
## Concatenate the matrices together
cu = concatenate( (cap, usp), axis=0 )
print cu

## Sort it
cu.sort( axis=0 ) 
print cu

## Do a forward difference from row to row
cu_diff = diff( cu, n=1, axis=0 )

## Now calculate the sum of the first three columns 
##  as it should be zero (or near zero)
cu_diff_s = sum( abs( cu_diff[:,:-1] ), axis=1 ) 

## Find the indices where it is zero
##  Change this to be <= eps if you are using float numbers 
indices = find( cu_diff_s == 0 )
print indices

## And here are the rows...
print cu[indices,:]
```

I contrived a dataset based on your example above. It appears to work. There might be a faster way to do it but this way you don't have to loop anything.  (I don't like looping :-) ).

[Updated]

Ok. So I added two more columns two each matrix. The second last column is a 1 in the cap and a 2 in the usp.  The last column is just an index into the original matrices.

```
## Store more info in the array
##  The first 4 columns are the initial data
##  The fifth column is a code of 1 or 2 (ie cap or usp)
##  The sixth column is the index into the original matrix

cap_code = concatenate(  (ones( (cap.shape[0], 1 )), reshape( r_[0:cap.shape[0]], (cap.shape[0], 1))), axis=1 )
cap_info = concatenate( (cap, cap_code ), axis=1 )

usp_code = concatenate(  (2*ones( (usp.shape[0], 1 )), reshape( r_[0:usp.shape[0]], (usp.shape[0], 1))), axis=1 )
usp_info = concatenate( (usp, usp_code ), axis=1 )

## Concatenate the matrices together
cu = concatenate( (cap_info, usp_info), axis=0 )
print cu

## Sort it
cu.sort( axis=0 )
print cu

## Do a forward difference from row to row
cu_diff = diff( cu, n=1, axis=0 )

## Now calculate the sum of the first three columns 
##  as it should be zero (or near zero)
cu_diff_s = sum( abs( cu_diff[:,:3] ), axis=1 )

## Find the indices where it is zero
##  Change this to be <= eps if you are using float numbers 
indices = find( cu_diff_s == 0 )
print indices

## And here are the rows...
print cu[indices,:]
print cu[indices+1,:]
```

It appears to work based on my contrived data. It is getting a tad convoluted so I don't think I would want to pursue this direction much further.

Good luck!

Comment: I think that you should loop if it will make the code faster. Often NumPy saves you from having to loop, but not always.

Comment: @nneonneo.  Yes, of course. The point is that almost always the underlying code (which has to loop at some level) is going to be faster than using Python to loop. List comprehensions might be slightly different as they are optimized.

Comment: This is close, but I need to know which values are from which array. Once I do the sort, I lose track of that.

Comment: @ith140: Ah... :-) I was going to add that in there. So you need to know the index in each array, correct?

Comment: @ith140: Ok, try that.  now the matrix and the row number are encoded and you can retrieve both. I believe it is correct.

Comment: @ith140:  If one of the answers fixes your issue, consider accepting it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's equivalent to return the row index using numpy is the following, which returns a boolean array, being 1 for the indices of same rows:

```
def find_rows_in_array(arr, rows):
    '''
    find indices of rows in array if they exist
    '''
    tmp = np.prod(np.swapaxes(
        arr[:, :, None], 1, 2) == rows, axis=2)
    return np.sum(np.cumsum(tmp, axis=0) * tmp == 1,
                  axis=1) > 0
```

The above returns indices only of non duplicate rows. If you want to return every possible row, then:

```
def find_rows_in_array(arr, rows):
    '''
    find indices of rows in array if they exist
    '''
    tmp = np.prod(np.swapaxes(
        arr[:, :, None], 1, 2) == rows, axis=2)
    return np.sum(tmp,
                  axis=1) > 0
```

which is a lot faster. You can interchange arrays as inputs so that to find for each array the corresponding indices. Enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains all the functionality you need, implemented in an efficient manner (that is, fully vectorized, thus no slow loops on the python level):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
c = npi.intersection(capind, uspind)
ia = npi.indices(capind, c)
ib = npi.indices(uspind, c)
```

Depending on how you value brevity vs performance, you might prefer:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
a = npi.as_index(capind)
b = npi.as_index(uspind)
c = npi.intersection(a, b)
ia = npi.indices(a, c)
ib = npi.indices(b, c)
```